# How am I going to reproduce Javascript bugs if I don't have a Mac & Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, testing, safari

Simple question... How am I going to reproduce Javascript bugs if I don't have a Mac & Safari?
Is it possible to run a legit copy of Mac OS on VMWare, or even better...run Safari in Windows?

Comment: Are you content that the implementation of Safari on Windows will be the same as the implementation of Safari on Mac (or iPhone, or whatever)?  I know that early iterations of IE on Mac vs. PC had completely different behavior.

Comment: I think that yes, they are pretty the same. IE on Mac used a different rendering engine, and was even more crappy.

Comment: And yes, it is possible to run a legit copy of MacOS on WMware (or event better, on VirtualBox) if you own one.

Comment: Safari engine behaviour is to all intents and purposes the same across mac and windows (there are no platform variations at all in JavaScriptCore)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple had a windows download for safari, but it's long-gone.

This is long out-of-date. Can't delete this accepted answer. :-(

Comment: Looks like as of Safari 6 they've eliminated the Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

> or even better...run Safari in Windows?

Sure: http://www.apple.com/safari/

Answer (score 1):

I expect that any JS bug will be repeatable in the Windows version of Safari as well.  However, for completeness, there are several services that allow you to view your web page in a metric boatload of browsers on OS X, Linux, and Windows, e.g. litmusapp.com. In this case, your question suggests that you may need more than a screenshot -- browsrcamp.com has a service which allows you to remote into a Mac and use a web browser interactively.

(Grain of salt: I haven't used any of these services myself.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely odd question.  Javascript can have bugs on any platform.  Why not download Safari for Windows, or use Firefox combined with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?